# How to prevent type P to get confounded to any in T | ((p: P) => T) (value or getter)?

Tags: typescript, function, types, typescript-generics, type-inference

I want that the user can specify a configuration value `T` either directly as this value or as a getter function that depends on a pre-defined parameter `P`. So I defined:

```
type Getter<T, P> = (param: P) => T;
type ValueOrGetter<T, P> = T | Getter<T, P>;
```

And when I tested this, everything worked fine:

```
const ex1: ValueOrGetter<string, number> =
  (param) => param.toString(); // type of param is number -> OK
```

But suddently a strange problem appeared when we do not know of what type `T` is, regardless of whether we define it as `any` or `unknown`: `P`, although explicitly defined, "gets lost", or rather becomes `any`!

```
const ex2: ValueOrGetter<unknown, number>
  = (param) => param; // type of params is any -> NOT OK
const ex3: ValueOrGetter<any, number>
  = (param) => param; // type of params is any -> NOT OK
```

It took me a while to figure out the problem. It very probably is that `any` and `unknown` include also functions, with a first parameter of any type. So I tried to exclude this case:

```
type ValueOrGetter2<T, P> = T extends ((...args: any[]) => any) ? T : ValueOrGetter<T, P>;
```

But that also does not work, probably because TypeScript does not "remember" in the ":"-part that `T` is *not* a function.

So what can I do to make sure that in all cases the type of `param` is inferred to `P`?

Comment: The problem occurs when `T` is wider than `Getter<T, P>`, because at that point, the type is reduced to `T` (`ValueOrGetter<unknown, number>` is equivalent to `unknown`). You could use something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPOZEm), but it's not clear if this is the behavior you want. Question for you: what is supposed to happen when `T` is wider than `Getter<T, P>`, reducing the type to just `T`?

Comment: @merryweather: Hm I think actually for my application the best option for this case would be to forbid it, that is to return `never`. But truth is, I know that all variables I will ever use for `T` will not be functions - I just cannot tell that TypeScript.

Comment: So [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR1GnW)? We can't really represent "not" types yet. There's some hacks you could probably do but it wouldn't play well with type inference. If that's okay then I'll probably write up an answer.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. Guess there is no better solution then at the moment. Thanks anyway